# subtracting dates from two arrays using for each loops in php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have created a form which takes dates as arrays:

```
  <form action="" enctype=”multipart/form-data” method="post" >
    Date1 <input type="date" name="tst1[]">
         </div> 
         <div id="div2">
          Date2 <input type="date" name="tst2[]">
        </div>  
         <input type="submit" value="test" name="submit">

    </form>
```

JavaScript:

```
var x=1
function appendRow1()
{
   var d = document.getElementById('div1');
    d.innerHTML += '<input type="date" name="tst1[]"/>';
}

    var x=1
function appendRow2()
{
   var d = document.getElementById('div2');
    d.innerHTML += '<input type="date" name="tst2[]"/>';
}
```

I am trying to subtract the dates that the user inputs in such a way that the dates at position 1 of both arrays get subtracted but the code subtracts all the dates  in all combinations.

php:

```
(isset($_POST['submit']) && is_array($_POST) == "test") {

    foreach($_POST['tst1'] as $date1){    
    foreach ($_POST['tst2'] as $date2){


    $diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));
        echo $diff;
        $years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
          $yy[] = $years;
        $average = array_sum($yy)/count($yy);
 echo $average . '<br>';
```

Comment: here you run a foreach in a foreach... you just need one foreach if $_POST[tst1][n] is to be compared to $_POST[tst2][n]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to subtract the position 1 of each array you can directly access the position without iterating the whole array:

```
$date1 = $_POST['tst1'][1];
$date2 = $_POST['tst2'][1];
```

If you want to subtract elements in the same position of both arrays you might use a for loop because it instantiates an iterator variable that you can use to set a position at both arrays.

Lets consider that both arrays have the same size.

```
$date1 = $_POST['tst1'];
$date2 = $_POST['tst2'];
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($date1); $i++){
   $diff = abs(strtotime($date2[$i]) - strtotime($date1[$i]));
   //...
}
```